# (Basic) Mod_rewrite breakdown

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm at few hours looking a various tuts on mod_rewriting, but anything I try myself never seems to work. What I'm hoping for is that I can give you guys the URL model, and get a working Rule and a breakdown of that Rule in return (I'm reasonably familiar with regex). That way I can adapt to future requirements also.

The structure is:
`domain.com/contents/page.php?id=123&u=page-slug`

What I want is for the user to type:
`domain.com/page-slug`
and be successfully redirected to the page in question.

From what I have read, this shouldn't affect PHP GET's - is this correct? Even if the id isn't actually in the address bar (obv. question, but I'm completely new to this)? It's surprising what tutorials leave out...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you determine the value of the id param?

Comment: The id's are auto generated as the pages are created and stored in the db. A page template then takes the url, gets the id, and displays the content stored for that id. Works fine, but it's very user-unfriendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ID is necesary then it will need to be present in the pretty url i.e. something like `domain.com/page-slug/page-id`.

To rewrite this to `page.php` add the following to your .htaccess in the root directory of `domain.com` as below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if not a file or a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# rewrite requests of the form domain.com/page-slug/123
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ contents/page.php?id=$2&u=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

If you want to learn more see this [list of .htaccess and mod_rewrite resources on the web](http://ulrichpalha.com/myblog/2012/01/13/best-htaccess-mod-rewrite-resources-on-the-web/)

Comment: Thanks. Still didn't work. I'm baffled - I'm using CPanel on an Apache server (so the module HAS to be on), the .htaccess file is in the root, and I am getting familiar enough with the syntax to follow what's happening, but it STILL won't work.

I'm trying it out in a subdir of the domain from now on, just to avoid messing with another install. So the structure will now have additional dir in there (`domain.com/dir/contents/page...`). I've moved the .htaccess file to the sub dir, but still nothing.

Comment: While we're about it - if the id is necessary, how does WordPress (as an example) work it's 'pretty permalinks'? Just searches the db based on the slug rather than the id?

Comment: Just to clarify, my current stucture is `domain.com/dir/contents/page.php?id=123&u=page-slug`. For now I will be typing `domain.com/dir/id/page-slug`

Answer (score 0):

> From what I have read, this shouldn't affect PHP GET's - is this correct? Even if the id isn't actually in the address bar (obv. question, but I'm completely new to this)?

If there is no id in the url, PHP GET won't get an id. But in the code you give it will work. Because you set a fixed id in the htaccess, the id will always be 123.

---

And why does it never seems to work? get you a error, a apache error, or...?
Have you add the mod_rewrite module to the httpd.conf? If not:

Browse to you httpd.conf file and open it in your editor. Look in the file for:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Remove the `#` in the front of the line, save the file and restart apache.

---

Your .htaccess file should look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(\d*?)/(.*?)$ page.php?id=$1&u=$2
```

Then it replace domain.com/id/page-slug to domain.com/page.php?id=id&u=page-slug

Comment: The id won't be 123, that was just filler. The id will vary for every page served. But you say GETs won't work then?

...and the module is on. I believe it's just a bad writing problem, as all I get are Page not Found errors

Comment: @Eamonn Then you need to add the id in the url. Something like `domain.com/id/page-slug`

Comment: Thanks for that, but no joy. This did not include the contents directory (`domain.com/contents/page.php?...`) but I believe that wouldn't make a difference if the url typed included it (`domain.com/contents/id/page-slug`)? Anyway, 500 error again.